How to prepend data to stdout without overwriting existing data?
I am trying to implement a console chat system. After connecting its supposed to ask for input() in a while True loop, receive messages and so print them. An example of the workflow:
Received: hello
Receved: there
Enter your message: 

The input prompt is shifted by a line each time a message is received. That being said, i want to prepend {message}\n to Enter your message when a message is received. \r overwrites stdout, and i want to avoid that behaviour.
Example code:
import sys

my_words = ['there', 'hello']

for word in my_words:
    sys.stdout.write(f'\r{word} ')

Desired output:
hello there

Actual output:
hello


stdout is a stream.  You cannot "prepend" to a stream.  Sometimes (as seems to be the case here) stdout is associated with a tty, and you can manipulate the position of the cursor on the tty by sending certain character sequences (eg, \r).  The point of this comment is that you should make the distinction between stdout and the tty very clear.  Once the distinction is well understood, the problems are easier to reason about.

Using a combination of '\r' and '\n'
import sys    

i = 1
while True:
    # simulate arrival of message every two cycles
    received_message = None
    if i % 2:
        received_message = "Hi there"
    i += 1

    # this should happen asynchronously, but formatting remains the same
    if received_message:
        sys.stdout.write(f'\rReceived: {received_message}\n')
    sys.stdout.write(f'\rEnter text: ')
    line = sys.stdin.readline()

Output
Received: Hi there
Enter text: first message
Enter text: second
Received: Hi there
Enter text: another message
Enter text: last
Received: Hi there
Enter text: ...

